# Why does Cain and Abel downgrade SSH version 2 to v 1.51?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, ssh

I am developing a lab exercise with Cain and Abel and want to know why it is [necessary to downgrade SSH](http://www.oxid.it/ca_um/topics/apr-ssh-1.htm) before attacking.

> Identification phase
>
> The server sends to the client an identification string of the form
>   "SSH-.-"; the client parses the
>   server's string, and sends a corresponding string with its own
>   information in response. Here APR-SSH-1 automatically replaces the
>   version specified by the server in the first packet in order to
>   downgrade the communication to SSH protocol v1.51.

What can SSH-2 do that version 1.51 can't?

Answer (score 1):

SSH-2 is a complete rewrite of SSH-1, as SSH-1 has inherent design flaws like [client authentication forwarding](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/684820/) and [packet injection](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/13877/). Ironically, the detection of the latter was [implemented](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/945216/) in a way that allowed executing code with the privileges of the daemon. [Ettercap](https://github.com/Ettercap/ettercap) can utilize the design flaws in MitM-attacks by stealing the session key and decrypting all the traffic.

> SSH1 MAN-IN-THE-MIDDLE
>
> When the connection starts (remember that we are the
> master-of-packets, all  packets go through ettercap) we substitute the
> server public key with one  generated on the fly and save it in a list
> so we can remember that this  server has been poisoned before.
>
> Then
> the client send the packet containing the session key ciphered with
> our key, so we are able to decipher it and sniff the real 3DES session
> key.  Now we encrypt the packet with the correct server public key and
> forward it  to the SSH daemon.  The connection is established
> normally, but we have the session key !!  Now we can decrypt all the
> traffic and sit down watching the stream !
>
> The connection will remain
> active even if we exit from ettercap, because  ettercap doesn't proxy
> it (like dsniff). After the exchange of the keys,  ettercap is only a
> spectator... ;)

SSH-2 provides strong cryptographic integrity checks, Diffie-Hellman key agreement and support for public-key certificates. The communication protocol must be downgraded to avoid those improvements.